# GetCookie extract information to a String

Tags: c#, cookies

I'm trying to get the numbers information from a cookie I get by Set-Cookie I need `&om=-&lv=1341532178340&xrs=` the numbers here

This is what I came up with:

```
 string key = "";
        ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        foreach (Cookie cookieValue in agent.LastResponse.Cookies)
        {
            list.Add(cookieValue);

        }
        String[] myArr = (String[])list.ToArray(typeof(string));
        foreach (string i in myArr)
        {

            // Here we call Regex.Match.
            Match match = Regex.Match(i, @"&lv=(.*)&xrs=",
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            // Here we check the Match instance.
            if (match.Success)
            {
                // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
                 key = match.Groups[1].Value;
            }
        }

 agent.GetURL("http://site.com/" + key + ".php");
```

The issue I'm having is I cannot change ArrayList to String (the error is: "At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the destination array type."), I thought you guys can help me maybe you can come up with a way to fix it or a better code to do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why don't you use List<dynamic> instead of ArrayList

Comment: I don't have much experience, if I use list<dynamic> what will be different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With first loop, you are building an `ArrayList` that contains `Cookie` instances. It's not possible to simply convert from `Cookie` to `string` as you are attempting to do just before the second loop.

A simple way to get values of all cookies is to use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<string> cookieValues = agent.LastResponse.Cookies.Select(x => x.Value);
```

If you are still using .NET Framework 2.0, you will need to use a loop:

```
List<string> cookieValues = new List<string>();
foreach (Cookie cookie in agent.LastResponse.Cookies)
{
    cookieValues.Add(cookie.Value);
}
```

Then, you can iterate over this collection just like you previously were. However, are you aware that if multiple cookies match your regex, the last one that matches will be stored to the `key`? Don't know how exactly you want this to work when there are multiple cookies that match, but if you simply want the first one, you can again employ LINQ to make your code simpler and do almost everything you need in a single query:

```
var cookies = agent.LastResponse.Cookies;
string key = cookies.Cast<Cookie>()
    .Select(x => Regex.Match(x.Value, @"&lv=(.*)&xrs=", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    .Where(x => x.Success)
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If there was no match, the `key` will be null, otherwise, it will contain the first match. 
The `Cast<Cookie>()` bit is necessary for type inference to kick in - I believe that `agent.LastResponse.Cookies` returns an instance of `CookieCollection` which does not implement `IEnumerable<Cookie>`.

Comment: Wow so much information thank you so much for the time and effort helping me with this one! :D I get the following error with this code: `Error 1 'System.Net.CookieCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Net.CookieCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: @MiLady `Cast()` and all other methods used in my sample are extension methods. They live in namespace `System.Linq`, so you need to add `using System.Linq;` to your code.

Comment: Aha ok I added it :) this soultion means it will only work on .net framework 3.5? my project works on 2 I guess this is a soultion but not for a framework 2 right?

Comment: And I'm new to LINQ if I want to scrape more (other) information with regex should I just copy this function or can add to it?

Comment: @MiLady Yes, this will only work with 3.5+ framework. I've edited my answer with a solution for .NET 2.0. Is there some specific reason you are still using 2.0? Regarding the regex scraping - you can certainly extend it to work with more complicated regex. At this point, I would recommend reading more about LINQ and related stuff such as extension methods - there is plethora of material available online.

Comment: @MiLady Please use the appropriate tools. No regex for query string parsing (stuff is optional and the order may vary): use [`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks a lot a lot for the info and the codes they work perfectly!