# Extract cookies info from response headers C#

Tags: c#, cookies, http-headers, httpresponse, httpwebresponse

I have some information that is available in a response header. One way would be to come up with a regex for it...Is there another way to work around this?

This is the header info:

```
Headers = {Cneonction: close
Content-Length: 87
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 05:51:37 GMT
Expires: Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: FUTWebPhishing-123456789=123456aavbc12334564856;Path=/;Domain=.ea.com;Expires=Wed, 1...
```

I want the value of FUTWebPhishing..Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can string.Split(';') the value of the Set-Cookie header and then find the element that contains "FUTWebPhishing".

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion on SO regarding this issue

Check it out:

[GetCookie extract information to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378467/getcookie-extract-information-to-a-string)