# Converting Set-Cookie string header to HttpWebCollection or name & value

Tags: c#, vb.net, cookies, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I've found many questions about this subject but NONE of the answers I've found is what I need.

I'm getting the Set-Cookie header from HttpWebResponse
I want to convert the SetCookie header to an HttpWebCollection or to an array of string that have each cookie as an item in the form "cookieName:cookieValue"

I hope someone help me..

** VB.NET / C# Solutions are acceptable.

Sample:

> fm=0; Expires=Sun, 13 Aug 2017 21:05:06 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; HTTPOnly,_twitter_sess=BAh7CSIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ25udHJvbGxlcjo9Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNo%250ASGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoPY3JlYXRlZF9hdGwrCEZFat1dAToMY3NyZl9p%250AZCIlZjA0Mzk5ZDIwMWVhNWZmNGFlMWY1ZmNjODQwZDllNjg6B2lkIiUxOGMw%250ANDcwYzI0YWUwMTM1OTgxYWI0ZTM3YWQ4NWYxMw%253D%253D--b075ea22b4a5da85ed7e669abaf5b3b334235a80; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure; HTTPOnly,personalization_id="v1_ESlBHR+jD8p4BKnk28JAdQ=="; Expires=Tue, 13 Aug 2019 21:05:15 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com,guest_id=v1%3A150265895158769848; Expires=Tue, 13 Aug 2019 21:05:15 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com,ct0=a450dfd9df2942fa0ee99c28273eee44; Expires=Mon, 14 Aug 2017 03:05:15 UTC; Path=/; Domain=.twitter.com; Secure

Comment: See following posting : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11378467/getcookie-extract-information-to-a-string I would put the cookies into a dictionary.

Comment: I didn't find anything that says how to convert a string cookie header into something that has cookieName & cookieValue

Comment: Can you post a sample of the cookie array.  Should be simple to split.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/raw/rA8r0nrM
I couldn't post it directly in a comment because it exceeds maximum characters allowed here.
Note: I'm not sure if twitter will always send them in the same syntax, I want something professional that should work for any value comes from Set-Cookie header.

Comment: What would you consider the cookie name?  The name should be unique string.

Comment: The cookie name shouldn't matter. The browser (ex: firefox) can handle cookies from any website with any cookie name. I want to do something like that.
No matter if it's HttpWebCollection or string array that each element have a cookie in the form "cookieName:cookieValue"

Comment: There is no name then use a collection like at the posting in my previous response : IEnumerable<string> cookieValues = agent.LastResponse.Cookies.Select(x => x.Value);

Comment: I think HttpWebResponse.Cookies is depending on CookieContainer that doesn't always save all cookies.
This code:
            Using res As HttpWebResponse = req.GetResponse()
                Dim cookiesString As String = res.Headers("Set-Cookie")
                MsgBox(res.Cookies.Count)

the cookiesString is something like the sample I commented before.
the messagebox shows "1" ---> It only gets the _twitter_sess cookie

Comment: You ask for all the cookies in the header.  The request may contain cookies.  When a request is sent the net library looks up the url in the user temp workspace to see if any cookies exist.  If there is a cookie is is sent in the request and the response may not have the cookie.  If the old cookie is expired a new cookie may be sent by the server.

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. :(

Comment: We are out of sync.  I was trying to understand why you were worried about "CookieContainer that doesn't always save all cookies".  You also said " I want to convert the SetCookie header to an HttpWebCollection".  So what cookies are missing?

Comment: When I used a new cookieContainer, I found that ONLY _twitter_sess was in the container after getting the response from server, but if I get cookies using "Set-Cookie" header I found all the cookies as the sample above shows.

Comment: You might want to put additional information from the comments into the question because it's hard to read it in the comments. I added your sample cookie text to the question (assuming the review gets accepted).

Comment: @Poosh Thanks for editing :)